# getting old JRE version error in eclipse even when the new version is already installed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I am new to Android Development.I installed Eclipse Kepler and then installed android SDK.
but on restarting eclipse i get the message that `JRE installed is 1.6,newer version neeeded`.but when i tried to install the latest version through terminal it says newest version is already installed in the system.

what i am doing wrong?

thanks.

**The error message window**

[image]

**And the following code when i tried to install the latest JRE 7.**

```
winnou@winnoupc10 ~ $  sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
[sudo] password for winnou: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre is already the newest version.
openjdk-7-jre set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-zh-hans language-pack-kde-en-base kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-zhcn
  language-pack-zh-hans-base firefox-locale-zh-hans language-pack-kde-zh-hans-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 736 not upgraded.
```

Comment: yeah i know that ,for that only i am using sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre,but it says as mentioned in the linux part of the question that newest version is already installed.

Comment: So just remove the already installed version first using `apt-get autoremove openjdk-7-jre` and then again try to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

I was getting the error because there were 2 versions of JRE installed and the default was JRE 6.so i changed the default version to 7 and it solved the issue.

Type the following command in terminal and follow the instructions.

**sudo update-alternatives --config java**

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.6                                1046      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 3

update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode.
```